# How to disable close button on figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I want to disable close button of figure in Matlab.
[image]
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have to override the `CloseRequestFcn` event handler, see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/165498). You can't hide or disable the close button, but you can ensure that user clicking on it won't have any effect.

Comment: thanks for your response, but it did not have any solution.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: @MasoudZayyani, here's how: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/139854-how-to-change-the-gui-close-function-whithout-changing-the-close-function-of-figures

Answer (score 1):

With this you can disable all:

```
set( findall(handles.your_uipanel, '-property', 'Enable'), 'Enable', 'off')
```

but to only disable the close one:

```
function closeRequestDemo
    figHdl = dialog('Name','Close Request Demo',...
                    'CloseRequestFcn',@cmdClose_Callback);...dialog creates a nice stripped down figure

    uicontrol('Parent',figHdl,...
              'String','Close',...
              'Callback',@cmdClose_Callback);


    function cmdClose_Callback(hObject,varargin)
        disp(['Close Request coming from: ',get(hObject,'Type')]);

        %do cleanup here
        delete(figHdl);

    end %cmdClose_Callback
end %closeRequestDemo
```

Sources here https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/290049

another way is:

```
% Get all the handles to everything we want to set in a single array.
handleArray = [handles.editText, handles.pushbutton, handles.listbox];
% Set them all disabled.
set(handlesArray, 'Enable', 'off');
```

Comment: thanks, but where I should insert first code? in **CloseRequestFcn** ?

Comment: @MasoudZayyani not exactly, I will add another alternative, you can check it here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/72650-hide-and-disable-uicontrols-in-groups you don't insert  it, you execute it.

Comment: @MasoudZayyani I updated the answer, I hope that helps you, don't forget accept the answer if it was helpful :)

Comment: thanks and sure, but i don't know where should I call **closeRequestDemo** function?

Comment: @MasoudZayyani pal! just like this, look! https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/run-functions-in-the-editor.html

Answer (score 1):

You can replace its function by typing:

```
set(fig_obj,'CloseRequestFcn','code to execute')
```

on my example I replace it by:

```
set(fig_obj,'CloseRequestFcn','set(fig_obj,"Visible","off");');
```

You can find more about here:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html#buiwuyk-1-CloseRequestFcn